# Unable to iterate through list of elements using same class

Tags: javascript

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('delButton');
    for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
        var attr = elems[i].getAttribute('data-rowid');
        elems[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log(attr);
        });
    }
```

When I click on any of the buttons, only the value of `data-rowid` attribute of the last element (delButton) is being output on the console. How do I print the `data-rowid` value associated with each of the buttons?

Comment: The linked question's answers explain why you're getting what you're getting. But the solution in this case is quite simple: Get rid of your current `getAttribute` line, and instead use `console.log(this.getAttribute("data-rowid"));` *inside* the event handler.

Comment: Also note that your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. You need to declare `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('delButton');
    for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
        elems[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log(this.getAttribute('data-rowid'));
        });
    }
```

You are not getting the expected result due to the fact the scope of the closure is such that only the last attr is evaluated.

While in the proposed solution you are extracted the attr from the element receiving the event

Comment: Thanks. I will look into JS closures further.

Comment: Obvious duplicates don't need answers, just close-votes (when you can) and comments if appropriate.